# How can I write a test case for an interface?

Tags: java, junit

I need to get 100% code coverage for an interface class, how can I write a junit test case to test an interface.

```
public interface RetrieveOperation {
  public RetrieveClassOfServiceProfileResponse
      retrieve(String login, RetrieveClassOfServiceProfileRequest request)
      throws Exception;
}
```

Comment: Test implementations of that interface.

Comment: You don't test the interface, you test the classes implementing the interface.

Comment: how are you measuring code coverage? i never heard of a code coverage tool that counted interface method declarations as uncovered.

Comment: You can't test interfaces. That's why you should trust software that is claimed to have 100% coverage: it results in programmers writing the most non-sense tests that will succeed always, but simply manage to call all lines.

Comment: If you ask such a question, you may want to read up on code testing and its use cases.

Comment: My class that implements the interface its 93% covered (only need to cover the return nulls and the throw exceptions are not covered) but the tool I am using it says that 0% coverage for the interface itself.

Comment: What tool are you using for test coverage? IntelliJ ignores all interfaces, it simply doesn't show them in the coverage report, even if they don't have a single implementation.

Comment: "*the tool I am using it says that 0% coverage for the interface itself.*" is that a concern for some reason? There is nothing to test, and therefore nothing to cover, in your interface.

Comment: @Turing85 Please help me on the same problem ... Actually we are using the JUNIT4 for the testing and coverage on the Sonar . In my Sonar interface class is not coverered, I need to cover it 100%, Could you please guide me on it.Thanks.Please help me on it

Comment: @dimo414 Please help me on the same problem ... Actually we are using the JUNIT4 for the testing and coverage on the Sonar . In my Sonar interface class is not coverered, I need to cover it 100%, Could you please guide me on it.Thanks.Please help me on it

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha 100% coverage is not a goal you should strive for. Coverage analyisis is a signal to help catch gaps in your testing, not something you need to arbitrarily get to 100%. In any case if you need help you should post a new question with more specifics.

Comment: @dimo414 Okay will post the question and let you know soon ..Thanks

Answer (score 3):

An interface doesn't do anything on its own, so there is no reason and no way to test it. It's only meaningful to test a class which implements an interface.

An exception to this are `static` methods (which can be easily tested because you don't need an instance) and the new `default` methods in Java 8. You don't have one like that in this example, but if you would have one, you would test it by creating a minimal class which implements the interface by implementing all non-default methods with a no-op and then use that to test the default methods.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, there's nothing in that interface to test.  You cannot have, and don't need, 100% coverage of a pure interface.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you can just write unit tests like you normally would for the individual implementations. To enforce an interface's behavior generally you can write a helper class / method(s) that checks the invariants of an arbitrary implementation, then have a test in the implementation's unit tests that calls that helper.

E.g.

```
public class RetrieveOperationVerifier {
  public static void assertValid(RetrieveOperation impl) {
    // assert impl behaves as expected
  }
}
```

---

```
public class ConcreteRetrieveOperationImplTest {
  // other tests

  public void invariantTest() {
    RetrieveOperationVerifier.assertValid(new ConcreteRetrieveOperationImpl());
  }
}
```

Comment: Having two tests delegating to the same test method, just using different implementations, should raise question why there are two classes with exactly same behaviour. And I doubt that it will solve coverage problem - as it looks to be related to the tool that generates it.

Comment: The intent with such a verifier is to enforce invariants (e.g. `List.iterator()` should return an `Iterator` that returns elements in the same order as incrementing calls to `List.get()`) regardless of implementation.  It is useful for enforcing shared behavior amongst different interfaces, it is *not* a standard unit test.